# Are there any tools for performing a vulnerability assessment of a MarkLogic server?

Tags: security, xquery, marklogic

Are there any tools for performing a vulnerability assessment of a MarkLogic server? If not, what kind of suite of tests can and should be executed?

Answer (score 0):

Many customers run [Nessus](https://www.esecurityplanet.com/products/nessus/) scans against the MarkLogic appserver ports.

The DISA STIG for [MarkLogic Server 9 STIG](https://dl.dod.cyber.mil/wp-content/uploads/stigs/zip/U_MarkLogic_Server_v9_V1R1_STIG.zip) has completed the approval process. It is published and available for download at cyber.mil  [Security Technical Implementation Guides (STIGs)](https://public.cyber.mil/stigs/)